# puppet-vcsrepo: Could not evaluate: undefined method `latest?'

Tags: puppet

I'm trying use [puppet-vcsrepo](https://github.com/bruce/puppet-vcsrepo/) to ensure that all my machines have the latest version of my code checked in from my hg repo. The first time I run my manifest, my code is successfully checked out, but every time puppet runs after that I get this error:

```
Could not evaluate: undefined method `latest?' for #<Puppet::Type::Vcsrepo::ProviderHg:0x7f830dc59cb0>
```

Here is the relevant part of my manifest:

```
vcsrepo {"/path/to/dir":
    provider => hg,
    ensure   => 'present',
    source   => 'me@mysource.com/source',
}
```

I'v tried using different revisions, or not specifying them at all as well as trying both ensure => present and ensure => latest. I'm just learning puppet, and am not very familiar with ruby, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be your usage of `revision => "HEAD"`. As far as i know HEAD is a git term. Just remove the revision part and you will get the latest version of your code by default.

README.HG.markdown:

> To get the default branch tip:

```
vcsrepo { "/path/to/repo":
     ensure   => present,
     provider => hg,
     source   => "http://hg.example.com/myrepo"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer phaer. Like I said, iv tried different revisions including the "HEAD" keyword, as well as not specifying a revision at all. They all have the same result.